# Cet endroit serait (le) lieu de naissance de ma fille

Tags: articles

*Autoportrait en noir et blanc* de Thomas Chatterton Williams :

> Je n'ai pas toujours conscience du charme de Paris, ni même d'être
> dans une ville qui n'est pas la mienne, mais cette nuit-là, en la
> voyant danser à travers la fenêtre, je réalisai soudain que cet
> endroit -- à la fois splendide et fondamentalement élogné de mes
> racines -- serait **le** lieu de naissance de ma fille.

*Paris-Briançon* de Philippe Besson :

> Qui est ce type qui débarque sans prévenir dans l'embrasure de son
> compartement, alors qu'autours, tout n'est qu'**obscurité** et
> **silence**.

Est-il possible d'omettre l'article devant *lieu* dans le premier extrait à l'instar de l'omission dans la deuxième phrase, devant *obscurité*, pour rendre la notion du mot *lieu* plus abstraite et plus intense ?

Comment: Autre exemple "là, tout n'est qu'ordre et beauté, luxe, calme et volupté. "

Answer (score 4):

Non. L'absence d'article (article zéro) n'est possible que dans des cas précis en français. La liste est assez longue, mais cette phrase de Williams n'en fait pas partie.

« Le lieu de naissance de ma fille » est un concept concret, unique. L'article défini *le* est obligatoire.

Dans « tout n'est qu'obscurité et silence », *obscurité* et *silence* sont des concepts généraux, dont on voit une manifestation. « Tout » n'est pas le concept d'obscurité en général, mais une partie de l'obscurité qui existe dans l'univers, donc on est dans le domaine d'application de l'article partitif : « tout n'est que de l'obscurité ». Cependant, avec l'article partitif, le verbe « être » ne convient pas vraiment, mais c'est plus une question de style que de grammaire. Il est préférable, dans un style littéraire, d'omettre l'article. La formulation choisie par Besson est évocatrice et un peu poétique, avec une métonymie entre le lieu « autour » et les perceptions que le protagoniste a de ce lieu. On pourrait aussi dire plus prosaïquement « autour, il n'y avait que de l'obscurité et du silence ».

À noter que ce n'est pas lié à la présence de « ne … que » ni d'« et ». On écrirait aussi : « tout n'est que silence », « tout est obscurité », etc.

Comment: +1 pour le concept linguistique de *article zéro".

Comment: Tout le monde, ou presque, sait que Lambie n'aime pas jlliagre, ni LPH ni moi ; pas la peine de le souligner... // Gilles, j'ai écrit dans le commentaire sous la réponse de jlliagre : à mon avis, l'articles défini et indéfini devraient aussi être possibles devant _obscurité_. Pourquoi ce n'est pas le cas ?

Comment: @Oreste L'obscurité est un concept général qui n'a pas d'instances particulières, et ce n'est pas un type d'obscurité, donc « une obscurité » ne convient pas. « Tout » n'est pas l'obscurité en général, donc « l'obscurité » ne convient pas.

Answer (score 1):

La fille n'aura qu'un seul lieu de naissance, Paris ici, donc l'article défini est attendu.

La conjonction *et* entraîne souvent la disparition de l'article (plus précisément l'article zéro comme le dit justement Gilles), mais ce n'est pas la raison qui l'explique ici. Ni *tout n'est qu'une obscurité (et un silence)*, ni *tout n'est que l'obscurité (et le silence)* ne sont satisfaisants. Si on insiste pour mettre un article, il faudrait que ce soit un partitif : *tout n'est que de l'obscurité (et du silence)*, mais la phrase devient alors très (trop) lourde.

Comment: Ici la conjonction *et* n'est pas du tout liée à l'absence d'article. Ce n'est pas une suppression d'article, mais un article zéro.

Comment: @Gilles Tu chipotes un peu... Je ne vois pas de différence fondamentale entre nos deux réponses.

Comment: Ta réponse n'est pas fausse, mais elle est trompeuse : elle donne l'impression qu'on n'aurait pas pu écrire « tout n'est qu'obscurité ».

Comment: @Gilles Ok, je comprends ce que tu veux dire. J'avais hésité à mettre *l'unique*, j'aurais du éviter de le faire.

Comment: Je pensais que les 4 options étaient possible ici : absence de l'article, article défini, article indéfini et article partitif. Comme dans _Je prépare **la** soupe_, _Je prépare **une** soupe_ et _Je prépare **de la** soupe_. Pourquoi dans mon exemple, l'articles défini et indéfini sont impossibles ? _Tout n'est qu'une obscurité_ voudrait dire une des plusieurs sortes d'obscurités ou une obscurité que l'on considère comme une unité ; _tout n'est que l'obscurité_, l'obscurité en général, son concept.

Comment: J'ai lu la réponse de Gilles, il dit que c'est surtout une question de style, en ce qui concerne l'article partitif.

Comment: *Tout n'est qu'une obscurité* n'est pas impossible grammaticalement, mais la logique rend difficile le concept d'obscurités différentes ou d'une obscurité particulière que serait "tout". *Tout n'est que l'obscurité* est lui aussi grammatical mais ne correspond à aucun contexte imaginable. Oui, utiliser l'article partitif poserait un problème de style, c'est ce que signifie "la phrase devient trop lourde".

Comment: Merci. :) _"Tout n'est que l'obscurité" est lui aussi grammatical mais **ne correspond à aucun contexte imaginable**._ Mais pourquoi ? Pourquoi il n'y a pas de contexte dans ce cas ?

Comment: @Oreste Parce que l'obscurité ne peut pas être **tout**, sauf à la limite si on parle de l'instant du Big Bang, ou avant que Dieu ait dit *Que la lumière soit !*

Comment: Pourquoi l'obscurité ne pourrait pas être tout ? C'est un "tout" relatif, et "obscurité" serait une notion abstraite. Je veux dire que je vous crois. Si vous dites que l'article définiti ne convient pas ici, c'est ainsi. Mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi.

Comment: @Oreste Quand on dit *Tout n'est qu'obscurité*, on sous-entend *Tout est plongé dans l'obscurité* mais ce tout obscur garde sa substance. Si on dit *Tout n'est que l'obscurité*, on dit que rien n'existe sauf l'obscurité, qu'il n'y a pas de matière.

Comment: D'accord, merci. J'essayerai de m'en souvenir. Mais je me demande comment les francophones savent tout cela, que _Tout n'est qu'obscurité_ = _Tout est plongé dans l'obscurité_ alors que _Tout n'est que l'obscurité_ = _rien n'existe sauf l'obscurité_. Ah, peut-être parce que  _qu'obscurité_ = _que de l'obscurité_ = une partie de l'obscurité absolue (ou globale). Donc, oui, maintenant, je perçois cette différence. L'obscurité globale contient toutes sortes d'obscurités, et _de l'obscurité_ est l'un de ces exemples, que l'obscurité globale englobe.

Answer (score -2):

Non, ce n'est pas possible.

L'absence dans « obscurité et silence » est due au fait que les deux noms sont reliés par une conjonction de coordination.

> [Cairn](https://www.cairn.info/revue-ela-2016-2-page-139.htm)
> En grammaire du français, l’absence de l’article est répertoriée (avec parfois mention de l’article zéro)
>
> Après des conjonctions de coordination (et, ou, ni) : Fromage ou dessert, fromage et dessert, ni vin ni bière.

- Après avoir placé fourchette et couteau sur la nappe, il se mit à table. (*user LPH*)
- Elle est toujours bien emmitouflée quand il fait froid, mais elle se passe de bonnet et cache-nez  dès qu'elle sent que la température est meilleure. (*user LPH*)
- Sel et poivre sont les ingrédients de base dans l'assaisonnement. (*user LPH*)
- Lorsque vous avez  perdu père et mère très jeune il peut vous arriver  à cause de cela de ressentir comme un vide dans votre  existence. (*user LPH*)
- Elle ne boit ni vin ni bière. (*user LPH*)

La suppression de l'article n'est pas faite dans le sens de rendre la notion des mots plus abstraite, ni plus intense ; on peut remarquer cependant que les mots qui sont ainsi reliés et privés d'article sont souvent de même nature (grandeur et décadence, Pommes et biscuits, Poètes et Paysans… ).

https://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3307

Comment: Ici la présence de *et* ne change rien à l'article. La phrase aurait pu être « tout n'est qu'obscurité » si l'auteur n'avait pas voulu réunir deux attributs. La suppression des articles dans certaines énumérations est un phénomène différent, où il ne s'agit d'ailleurs pas d'un article zéro mais d'omettre un article quel qu'il soit.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Je trouve ceci : « tout n'est qu'une vapeur légère , qu'une ombre , que le néant même ; rien n'est grand dans l'homme … » ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Sainte_Bible_3/cBkMGbs6v6oC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22tout+n%27est+qu%27une%22&pg=PA322&printsec=frontcover)). Ne pourrait-on pas dire que soit l'un soit l'autre des deux principes, celui pour « n'est que » et celui pour « et », a son effet ?