# Il y a (la) présence d’une lésion cavitaire

Tags: articles

Cité du rapport d'un scan dentaire :

> Il y a **présence** d’une lésion cavitaire (approximativement 8.8mm de
> hauteur x 8.0mm de longueur x 6,5mm de largeur) contenant...

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50139/cet-endroit-serait-le-lieu-de-naissance-de-ma-fille), il n'y a qu'une seule présence de lésion, donc l'article défini aurait dû être employé.

Dans ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49900/avoir-un-entrainement), on dit qu'il est courant d'omettre l'article après "avoir" lorsqu'on parle d'une activité programmée et généralement récurrente. Mais dans mon exemple, il ne s'agit pas d'une activité.

Pourquoi alors il est possible d'omettre l'article devant *présence* ?

Comment: Sans l'article, ça fait médecin légiste.

Answer (score 1):

En fait, non, l'article défini aurait pu être employé.

*[Exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trouve%20la%20pr%C3%A9sence%20d%27%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)*

- Il y a un site au lieu dit « ElArrouiya » à 8 km au nord, ou on trouve la présence d'un équidé et un félin. Hadjar Berrik à 2 km à l'ouest, on ne rencontre aucune figuration de style monumental mais de nombreux animaux dans le style de
- Dès la fin du XIVè , on y trouve la présence d'écrivains en lettres de forme ( uu nommé Mathieu ou Mattei )
- De l'autre côté se trouve la présence d'une littérature alternative se développant en dehors des circuits de l'édition et de la diffusion traditionnels.

« [Trouve une présence de](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trouve+une+pr%C3%A9sence+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=) » n'est pas représenté. « [Y a une présence de](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22y%20a%20une%20pr%C3%A9sence%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » ne donne apparemment que des faux positifs.

Par contre, « [il y a présence de](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+y+a+pr%C3%A9sence+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20y%20a%20pr%C3%A9sence%20de%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20y%20a%20pr%C3%A9sence%20de%3B%2Cc0) » est courant : [exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il%20y%20a%20pr%C3%A9sence%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

[image]

Il s'agit d'une tournure idioamtique : parfois après « il y a », l'article est omis.

voir page  dans « [Cairn.Info, l'absence d'article](https://www.cairn.info/revue-ela-2016-2-page-139.htm) ».

Comment: T'as cherché dans les documents écrits par les les médecins légiste, par exemple?

Comment: Merci ! Comment comptez-vous les pages dans ce livre ? Il n'y a pas de numération là.

Comment: Donc, il en va de même du tour "Il y a prescription" ? _Paris-Briançon_ de Philippe Besson : -- Vous préférez peut-être qu'on discute d'autre chose ? -- Non, il y a prescription. Et puis, quand on y songe, c'est très banal, une séparation.

Comment: @Oreste Esayez maintenant ; l'url était fausse. Utiliser « Shift+F » pour trouver « il y a ».

Comment: @Oreste Ce n'est pas automatique ; remarquez que selon le texte il ne s'agit que de certains noms (parfois). Néanmoins, dans le cas de « prescription » l'article est omis presque toujours (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+y+a+la+prescription%2Cil+y+a+prescription&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20y%20a%20la%20prescription%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20y%20a%20prescription%3B%2Cc0) Par exemple, on ne dira pas « il y a avis du préfet », mais « il y a l'avis du préfet ».

Comment: Merci pour le lien.

Answer (score 1):

La phrase est idiomatique mais le ***il y a***, inutile, pourrait être supprimé :

> Présence **d’une** lésion cavitaire contenant...

Réciproquement, ***présence*** peut aussi être considéré comme inutile et redondant, puisqu'il signifie ***il y a***, et on pourrait écrire :

> Il y a **une** lésion cavitaire contenant...

L'article défini est exclu :

> Il y a <s>**la**</s> présence d’une lésion cavitaire contenant...

mais serait utilisé si on remplaçait *il y a* par *on observe*:

> On observe **la** présence d'une lésion cavitaire contenant...

Dans ce cas aussi, ***présence*** n'apporte rien :

> On observe **une** lésion cavitaire contenant...

L'article indéfini est plus ou moins possible mais en replaçant *d'une* par *de* :

> Il y a **une** présence de lésion cavitaire contenant...

La phrase est cependant bien lourde.

Comment: Mais pourquoi on omet l'article dans la 2ème phrase ? Tout simplement, parce que c'est ainsi ? C'est un tour idiomatique, et c'est tout ? // Dans ma question, dans la 3ème phrase, j'ai écrit _D'après ce fil, il n'y a qu'**une seule présence de lésion**..._ Est-ce que j'ai bien mis les articles ? Je pense que oui.

Comment: Oui, tu as bien mis les articles et la phrase est correcte. On ne dirait cependant pas ***il y a deux présences de lésion*** mais ***on observe la présence de deux lésions***.